# UDP recvfrom data not displaying properly

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Html file has the following content

**Helloworld.html**

```
Hello World
Testing Echo Server
```

**Output from Server**

[image]

**Client Code**

```
//Pack contents into UDP packet and send
while(1) {
    //Check for Validity of File
    readSize = fread(buffer, 1, bufferSize, currentFile);
    if (readSize <= 0) {
        if (ferror(currentFile) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read from file %s\n", inputFile);
            free(buffer);
            fclose(currentFile);
            close(sDescriptor);
        }
        break;
    }
    //Send Data
    if (send(sDescriptor, buffer, readSize, 0) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Send failed\n");
        free(buffer);
        fclose(currentFile);
        close(sDescriptor);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

**Server Code**

```
/* Receive Data & Print */
unsigned int len = sizeof(cad);
int size = sizeof(buffer);
while (1) {
    charactersRead = recvfrom(sd, buffer, size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cad, &len);
    /* Print Address of Sender */
    printf("Got a datagram from %s port %d\n", inet_ntoa(cad.sin_addr), ntohs(cad.sin_port));
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    if (charactersRead < 0 ) {
      perror("Error receiving data");
    } else {
      printf("GOT %d BYTES\n", charactersRead);
      /* Got something, just send it back */
      //sendto(sd, buffer, charactersRead, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&cad, &length);
    }
  }
```

Any more information needed, I will be willing to post. 
The client will send the contents of a file as a UDP packet and the server receives it and prints it out. However, as you can something is corrupted. I have no idea why this is doing this, If I switch the parameters of the third argument in `recvfrom` i get different outputs. For example, If i make the size larger it will actually print out the whole thing, but with corrupted chars at the end. What is the correct way of determining the size? That's if that's the problem.
Here's what happens when the size argument is made larger.
[image]

This is closer to what is expected, but still corrupt bits are there.

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the output you posted. It's in a different order.

Comment: @EJP the second output is what happens after changing the size variable.

Comment: Both outputs show the data after the size. The code prints the size after printing the data. Either this is not the real code or this is not the real output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

That should be

```
printf("%.*s\n", charactersRead, buffer);
```

You're ignoring the count.

And if `buffer` is a pointer, `sizeof buffer` is only going to give you the size of the pointer, not the size of what it points to.

Comment: This works, but the problem still remains: the entire datagram is not being received.

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof buffer`? Is `buffer` a pointer by any chance? If so, do you understand the difference between the size of a pointer and the size of what it points to? Which is given by `sizeof *buffer`? And if so *why* is `buffer` a pointer? Normally the receive buffer is a local array on the stack.

Comment: Buffer is intitially declared a pointer, then given a size like an array dynamically.

Comment: So that's the problem. You should use the actual size. `sizeof buffer` is only the size of the pointer itself.

Answer (score 5):

You are using printf() on a buffer that is not null terminated. The eight bytes you received are "Hello Wo", the rest is not corruption, just stuff in memory past the end of your buffer. You need to use the byte count when displaying your output.

Comment: Shouldn't it send the whole data? It's only receiving eight bytes.

Comment: In UDP, `send/sendto` and `recv/recvfrom` are 1-to-1, yes.  UDP sends and receives complete datagrams - you receive exactly what was sent.  This is not the case in TCP, though. Have your sender output how many bytes it is sending, then compare that to your receiver's output. Janm is right though, you need to take the read data length into account when calling `printf()`. Either put a null terminator at the end of the read data, or else pass the actual length to `printf()` as a width/precision specifier.